# Uploading Web API to Azure makes Blazor Web App not accessible

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have been trying to understand what I am doing wrong for about a week now. Here is my structure:

[image]

I am publishing Blazor server app to number 1. Then I have created ASP.Net Web API, tested it on my localhost and would like to upload it to Azure to access it online. However after I am hitting Publish in Visual Studio, my entire Blazor app is not any longer accessible from https address. Then I am Publishing my Blazor app again from Visual Studio and it is working fine again. What I am doing wrong? Is there any guide how to publish Blazor Web App and then host ASP.Net Web API on the same Azure account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"on the same Azure account" is of course possible, but when you have 2 projects you will need 2 App Services, maybe under 1 service plan.

Two services cannot share the same URL.

I don't think you need an "API Management service" but I could be wrong.

Comment: Need to try creating new App Service right away

Comment: And make sure to reconfigure your Publish profiles.

Comment: This API Management and WEB API Publishing has lead me into wrong path. Here is a good example how to do it right way and just skip whole API part: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MP4zatl3jF8